# React native video error code 1001 on list of videos

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

When i try to load my videos in I get the following error:

```
error: {domain: "NSURLErrorDomain", code: -1001}
target: 2149
```

That's it, there is no other information and I couldnt find anything on the web. If you have any idea what this means please let me know. All URLs I am using do in fact exist. I am loading a vertical list of horizontal lists of videos , so you can scroll left and down. The videos that get this error are totally sporadic:

```
x = [1 , 2, 3, 4, 5,]
y = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
z = [15,]
```

Sometimes this error is on video 1, 4, 5, 7, 15, etc,
Totally random, sometimes it happens to many, sometimes to none. My render ahead horizontally is 3 videos and my render ahead vertically is 2

Comment: do you already have a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, bare with me because this was 6 months ago, but there is something implicit in react native where it won't load more than 12 (I think, it could be more I don't remember now) video players at once, so you have to track the state of each render and ensure you don't load too many or they simply won't load at all.